# AWS: web server: Is it better to use Docker or configure the server on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, archlinux

I am using archlinux on my development. I am trying to use a free tier AMI for EC2 in AWS.

I have found Amazon linux 2 as one of the AMI's

I didnt find arch linux AMI in free tier.

I know using docker i can still use archlinux and keep the environment same

The reason why i want to use arch is i am familiar with the package management which is very crucial for ease on any particular linux distribution.

So will using Docker effect AWS performance and is Docker worth using at all.

Or should i get used to the AMI linux distribution.

Comment: If you’re using Docker look at Fargate. No servers to manage.

Comment: why fragate is more expensive than EC2

Comment: No servers to manage/configure. Less chance of your account getting breached.

Comment: do we have a free trail in fragate also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like Archlinux use the Archlinux Docker.

The Docker overhead is very small.

Using Docker will also make it easy to port your setup to any location: other cloud, desktop, other OS.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is perfect to go. Further, consider that, in [different regions](https://aws.amazon.com/it/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/), you can use the [AWS fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/). It allows you to start docker containers (scaling them up and down, etc) without having to manage servers (EC2 instances).